# The implicit binding in laravel (5.6) returt a empty object

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.6, laravel-blade, laravel-resource

i'm trying to use the method 'show' in a controller but when it return a empty object.

Since this view:

```
@foreach ($usuarios as $usuario2)
  <h2>{{$usuario2->nombre}}</h2>
  <a href="prurequests/{{$usuario2->id}}">ver mas2...</a>
@endforeach
```

Through tis route:

```
Route::resource('/prurequests','PruebasControllers\PrurequestsController');
```

To this controller's method:

```
public function show(Usuario2 $usuario2)  // Ruta con implicing biding
 {
     return $usuario2;
 }
```

This is the model:

```
class Usuario2 extends Model
{
    Protected $fillable = ['nombre'];
}
```

I tried with this and it works

View:

```
@foreach ($usuarios as $usuario2)
  <h2>{{$usuario2->nombre}}</h2>
  <a href="impli/{{$usuario2->id}}">ver mas...</a>
  <a href="prurequests/{{$usuario2->id}}">ver mas2...</a>
@endforeach
```

Route

```
Route::get('impli/{usuario2}', function 
(fractalwebpage\PruebasModelos\Usuario2 $usuario2) {
  return $usuario2;
});
```

It bring me tha data ubt i had to put the nae of the model in the route and.
e need to do it but Through  the controller.

Comment: By default, Laravel uses the last segment of the url as the placeholder of the request or a resource route, so in your controller method you can inject your model but with a different name `public function show(Usuario2 $prurequests)`

Comment: the question is unreadable due to typos, spelling and grammar mistakes. i cannot understand what is being asked here. downvoted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, Laravel uses the last segment of the url as the placeholder of the request of a resource route, so in your controller method you can inject your model but with a different name `public function show(Usuario2 $prurequests)`

But a more definite solution would be to just change the parameter in the route definition

```
Route::resource('/prurequests','PruebasControllers\PrurequestsController', ['parameters' => ['prurequests' => 'usuario2']]);
```

This way, you can continue using your controllers the way they currently are

```
public function show(Usuario2 $usuario2)  // Ruta con implicing biding
{
   return $usuario2;
}
```

Comment: use this ´public function show(Usuario2 $prurequests)´ does not work but the second goes well.
i consider this force us to do some things so restricted

Answer (score 0):

When you try to implicit binding in resource controller then at time of creating resource controller you have to add an `--model` option

```
php artisan make:controller PrurequestsController --resource --model=Usuario2
```

> **Specifying The Resource Model** If you are using route model binding and
>   would like the resource controller's methods to type-hint a model
>   instance, you may use the --model option when generating the
>   controller:

Check details https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/controllers#resource-controllers

Comment: You don't add placeholders when using `Route::resource()`.

Comment: i asked because i saw this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fAtQ5w9QDoU&index=20&list=PLIddmSRJEJ0sxS-RmqdRMlkyWOQWvEGEt
min 10:00 and here he use implicit binding in a resource without a placeholder.

Comment: i asked because i saw this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fAtQ5w9QDoU&index=20&list=PLIddmSRJEJ0sxS-RmqdRMlkyWOQWvEGEt
min 10:00 and here he use implicit binding in a resource without a placeholder.
he pass ans route like 
    ´<a href="/triners/{{$trainer->id}}´....> where the model is trainer

Comment: @DiegoIzquierdoDussan it is working for me with resource too. updated answer check it